# Library similar to ngx-treeview that supports anugluar 7?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular7, ngx-treeview

Just upgraded my project from angular 5 to angular 7, but found out that ngx-treeview does not support angular 7.

No errors were shown that could be related to the plugin, but whenever a new plugin is add or remove. Warning about `npm WARN ngx-treeview@6.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.` shows up, also after a quick check on the official site, it supports upto 6. Found this [request feat](https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview/issues/180).

Does anyone know a package that is similar to treeview but Support angular 7?

Comment: If you have tried that component in angular 7, show what you have done, and what is not working, show errors messages you found.  SO is not the right place in case of asking for components or library. [can-i-ask-for-code-libraries-and-plugins-on-stack-overflow-or-is-that-better-su](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289843/can-i-ask-for-code-libraries-and-plugins-on-stack-overflow-or-is-that-better-su)

Comment: hey @HDJEMAI, I ran the project but i didn't get any error that could relate to treeview. But i received warning about the dependencies needs angular 6 and from the official site, it supports upto angular 6. Where would be a good place to ask for lib or dependencies?

Comment: Please update your question with any helpful message.